# is "ServerAdmin email@domain.tld" required in the VirtualHost in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd, httpd.conf

I rather not have

```
 ServerAdmin
```

in my VirtualHost because all it does is attract spam.

has no use what so ever.

can it be ignored ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need it.

I just checked on a server with over a hundred apache virtual domains, none of them have ServerAdmin defined.  The ServerAdmin is commented out in the main config file (httpd.conf) and I guess there hasn't been a problem so far.

In fact it seems like apache [no longer displays the ServerAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798272/benefits-of-serveradmin-directive-in-apache2) in any event?